# Add image to notification when using sendToTopic method

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use [sendToTopic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging-1#sendtotopic) method to send notification to a topic, How can I add image to the notification?
There is no option such as `notification.imageUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this -

```
 const message: TopicMessage = {
  topic: reqData.topic,
  data: {
    abc: reqData.abc
  },
  notification: {
    title: reqData.title,
    body: reqData.body,
    imageUrl: reqData.imageUrl
  }
};

// messageRes is a message ID string.
const messageRes = await admin.messaging().send(message);
```